# Partial YouTube looper in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, youtube, browser-extension

Is there a Firefox extension that does what this Chrome [extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/looper-for-youtube/iggpfpnahkgpnindfkdncknoldgnccdg), "[Looper for YouTube](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/looper-for-youtube/iggpfpnahkgpnindfkdncknoldgnccdg)", does? (The official looper can only loop full video.)

[image: screenshot of extension]

> Auto replay videos with ONE-CLICK, able to customise features such as AUTO LOOP toggle, setting loop counts and loop portion.
>
> […]
>
> Have you ever wanted to watch to the same video on the YouTube™ without pressing replay button every time at the end of the video? With Looper for YouTube you will get a loop button under the YouTube player. After you press the button, video will repeat itself infinitely.
>
> Key Features:
>
> - ** Able to set default auto loop on every video **
> - Able to set loop in a portion/range
> - Able to set loop how many time you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [YouTube Parts Looper & Bookmarker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-parts-looper/) was written to enable a DJ-like use of YouTube, it suits this purpose as well if one doesn't mind typing in the timestamps.